# What is the point of adding const to the declaration of std::lock_guard<>?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, constants, mutex

In some example code I see the following with a `const`:

```
const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock( mux );
```

In some other examples, no `const`.

Any technical or semantic difference?  Does the const one somehow signal something interesting to the reader?  For instance is it intended to remind them that nothing further can happen to lock?

Comment: It's good pratice to make non changing variables `const`. 1. To indicate they don't change, 2. to help the compiler optimize code and 3. to prevent accidental changes

Comment: This is very much up to the individual programmer. Yes it has a semantic meaning (in that the object can't be modified), but it also have an informational meaning (the object *won't* be modified). Which one the author intended is impossible to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `const` to the declaration provides a free documentation that *this instance is immutable* without having to look into `std::lock_guard` declaration.

Of course it doesn't provide any performance benefit as `std::lock_guard` is immutable by nature but all the readers of your code may not know that.

Answer (score 8):

A `const` instance of `std::lock_guard` behaves identically to a non-`const` one. There is no benefit to adding the `const`, nor to omitting it.

The type has no member functions, and is not copyable or movable, so there is essentially no difference at all.

I would consider the `const` as noise and remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Some people consider that mutable by default in C++ is less than ideal and make *everything* `const` instead. `const` can save one from programming errors resulting from unwittingly modifying that variable.